Multi-panel Table in Stargazer
I try to create a multi-panel table using stargazer and starpolishr. The first panel table is a summary statistics table, and the second panel table is a regression table. Here is an example of the code I used -
# Summary Table for Panel 1
star.out = mtcars %>% 
  stargazer(type = 'latex',
            summary.stat = c(
      'n',
      'mean',
      'sd',
      'p25',
      'median',
      'p75'
    ),
    digits = 3,
    label = "tab:overallsummary",
    title = "Summary Statistics of Variables",
    single.row = TRUE, 
    no.space = TRUE, 
    font.size = "scriptsize",
    column.sep.width = "5pt",
    header = FALSE, 
    notes.align = "l",
    covariate.labels = c (
      'MPG',
      'CYL',
      'DISP',
      'HP',
      'DRAT',
      'WT',
      'QSEC',
      'VS',
      'AM',
      'GEAR',
      'CARB'
    )
    )

# Regressions for panel 2
reg1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp, data = mtcars)
reg2 <- lm(cyl ~ cyl + disp, data = mtcars)
reg3 <- lm(mpg ~ hp + drat, data = mtcars)
reg4 <- lm(cyl ~ hp + drat, data = mtcars)
reg5 <- lm(disp ~ hp + qsec, data = mtcars)


# Panels 1 amd 2 Output 

panel1 <- stargazer::stargazer(
  star.out,
  float = TRUE,
  header = FALSE,
  model.numbers = FALSE,
  omit.table.layout = "n",
  multicolumn = FALSE,
  #dep.var.caption = "",
  type = "latex",
  align = TRUE, 
  digits = 3,
  df = FALSE, 
  digits.extra = 3
  #,nobs = TRUE
  #,omit.stat = c("rsq", "adj.rsq", "ser") 
)

# Panel 2 output
panel2 <- 
  stargazer::stargazer(
  reg1, reg2, reg3, reg4, reg5,
  float = TRUE,
  header = FALSE,
  model.numbers = FALSE,
  omit.table.layout = "n",
  multicolumn = FALSE,
  dep.var.caption = "",
  type = "latex",
  align = TRUE, 
  digits = 3,
  df = FALSE, 
  digits.extra = 3,
  nobs = TRUE,
  omit.stat = c("rsq", "adj.rsq", "ser")
)


But When I run the following in an Rmarkdown PDF, the table is not generated; it just shows some latex words. Do you have any idea how I can solve this issue? I created multi-panel table, with each panel containing regression table, but I am not able to create a table in which both panels do not contain the regression tables. I tried to follow this link - Multi-panel regression tables in R, but have not been able to solve the issue.

#### Final Output in Rmarkdown PDF

  starpolishr::star_panel(
  panel1, 
  panel2,
  panel.names = c(
    "Summary Statistics", 
    "Regression Results"
  ), 
  panel.label.fontface = "bold",
  same.summary.stats = FALSE, 
  same.lhs.vars = FALSE ) %>% 
  star_notes_tex(
    note.type = "threeparttable",
    note =  c("blah blah")
  ) %>%
  cat

